# How to send a request upload a file with java object like @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile file ,@RequestBody User userDetailsId?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying so much to send a request like CommonsMultipartFile and one java object.I constructed controller like follows.

```
public @ResponseBody Response upload(@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile userPhoto, @RequestBody UserDetails userDetailsId,
            @RequestParam String authCode)
//method impl
}
```

when I am trying to send request from postman:
In form-data uploaded image(1st screenshot) ,In Body-raw(2nd screenshot) i am sending user object.This is what I done.Can you please tell me how to fix this issue.Or can you please suggest me right way if I am wrong.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"), produces = "application/json", consumes = "image/*")
public RestResponse save(@RequestParam("bankAddress") String bankAddress, @RequestParam("bankNameAr") String bankNameAr, @RequestParam("bankNameEn") String bankNameEn, @RequestParam("bankPhone") String bankPhone, @RequestParam("bankStatus") BigDecimal bankStatus, @RequestParam("countryId") long countryId,
        @RequestParam("bankImage") MultipartFile file) {

.
.
.
}
```

and use `byte[] data = file.getBytes();` to get file into byte[] and use for further process.